# Send CTRL+SHIFT+R to Web page in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to a webpage using protractor, but it's not working. I tried following command, but it's not working. This command opens the same page in new tab.

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT).sendKeys('R').perform();
```

I need to do this to clear browser cache so that some of the web page field values that are stored earlier gets deleted. I tried using following in `afterEach` block, but that did not work.

```
browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
  browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
```

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+R` refreshes the page, not opens in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, found this by looking at a different question for sending key combinations. There is also an example in the [protractor source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ed955e56a839d7f69da43acb6755763220d3681d/lib/selenium-webdriver/webdriver.js#L452) that shows this method for `element.sendKeys()`.

```
browser.actions()
  .sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.SHIFT, 'r')
  .perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but it did not work. It basically did not perform anything and moved onto next step.

Comment: Since this option did not work, i used restartBrowserBetweenTests: true in conf.js which will restart browser after each test and all previously stored web page field values are cleared.